# Mapping Strings to Functions with Different Return Types

Tags: c++, function, c++11, dictionary, overloading

I've seen variants of this question asked, but they usually involve functions returning the same type. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void checkType(int x){
    cout << "we got an int: " << x << endl;
}

void checkType(float x){
   cout << "we got a float: " << x << endl;
}

int getInt(){
   return 1;
}

float getFloat(){
   return -101.23f;
}

int main(){
   map<string, function<float()> > myMap({
      {"int", getInt},
      {"float", getFloat}
   });

   checkType(myMap["int"]());
   checkType(myMap["float"]());

   return 1;
}
```

The goal here is to call different versions of an overloaded function (checkType) depending on what the mapped function returns. Obviously the checkType(float) function ends up getting called twice because my map thinks all its functions return floats.

Is there a good way to do this? And is it at all good practice? I've found a different solution, but I think if something like this is legitimate it could be pretty sexy.

Comment: Consider: `string s = "int"; checkType(myMap[s]());` Do you want this to call `checkType(int)`? I don't see how this could work. Which overload to call is determined entirely at compile-time - it can't possibly change at run-time depending on the value a string variable happens to have.

Comment: Eh the float function shouldn't be called twice. You should get a compilation failure.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Even though the return type is not part of the function's signature?

Comment: @BЈовић The function's signature is irrelevant; the program clearly has a call to `getInt` followed by a call to `getFloat`, so why is `getFloat` being invoked twice instead?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Weird. I compiled, and `getFloat()`  is not  called twice. `checkType(float x)` is called two times.

Comment: @BЈовић Ah right yes okay so what's happened here is that I've misunderstood the OP's "the float function ends up getting called twice" (is it so hard to use the actual name and signature!!). That explains it all then.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry about that, I understand the confusion. I meant that the float version of the overloaded function is getting called twice. Both getInt and getFloat are being called, but it seems to me that the return value gets cast to a float when it's returned (perhaps due to the fact that the map thinks all its functions return floats.) Again, sorry, and thanks for the response.

Comment: @user197 No apology necessary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already found out, the way you implemented it, is not going to work, since the functions stored in map are returning float.

A proper way is to use type erasure, but if you use void* you have to take care of proper casting. Another option is to use `boost::any`, or `QVariant`.

This example uses `const void*` to erase types :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void callForInt(const void* x){
    const int* realX = static_cast < const int* >( x );
    cout << "we got an int: " << *realX << endl;
}

void callForFloat(const void* x){
    const float* realX = static_cast < const float* >( x );
    cout << "we got a float: " << *realX << endl;
}

int main(){
   map<string, function<void(const void*)> > myMap({
      {"int", callForInt},
      {"float", callForFloat}
   });

   const int v1 = 1;
   const float v2 = -101.23f;

   myMap["int"](&v1);
   myMap["float"](&v2);
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the answer. My solution was something similar...though I'm a bit of a noob at this. I tried both using typeid(to check which type is getting sent in) as well as a dynamic cast to check which pointer returns valid...if that makes any sense. Anyway, the goal was to have the mapped functions take in the same set of parameters but return different things. Since the mapped function always returns void this doesn't really satisfy me, but I understand the issue and will accept your answer.

Comment: @user1973454 With `boost::any` and `QVariant`, you can get some kind of type safety (if you use their casts, and not reinterpret_cast or c-style casting)